# What is cnumpy.core.multiarray? How to release(delete) it?

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, jvm

I use jmap to dump the memory use and find a data structure named `cnumpy.core.multiarray`, this object belongs to `org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD`

It takes a large part of memory, seems to be created during RDD is created, but I have not find a method to release it from memory.

What is this data type? How to release it from memory?